# How to get Subcategory and its products with details in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, submenu

I want to show subcategory with its products in list.phtml. I am trying

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <li>

                    <?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                        <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                        <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                                    <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName(); 
                                     $category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('name', $_subcategory->getName());
                                    print_r($category->getData());

                                ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

it will show all sub category with its details but how can i find subcategory products and details through it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

         <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($category->getData());?>

        <?php
           $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
           $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->load();
        ?>

        <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
           <?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($product->getData());?>
        <?php endforeach ; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```